What are the meaning of the components of the Dirac bispinor?
I`ve recently started to study the Dirac Equation, but I simply cannot understand what the components of the bispinor mean. I firstly thought that they meant individually a state of spin and positive or negative energy, but I found an article in wikipedia which found the positive energy solutions, but they had non-zero components in the bottom two entries, which were supposed to mean negative energy. I already have good foundations on quantum mechanics and spinors but this seems alien to me. I appreciate very much any response.

"I've recently started to study the Dirac Equation..." Do your recently started studies include reading/reviewing a textbook? If so, the textbook may contain the explanation you seek. If not, you could try Peskin and Schroeder's textbook. They discuss the Dirac equation from a fairly modern perspective.

You are right, I didnt read any textbooks, I am relying only in internet sources.  Unfortunately I dont think I am now able to afford a textbook of that price. If you have a reccomendation of any site or youtube video which could respond my question I would be really grateful.

I do not have a youtube video to recommend.
